Dokku nextjs suddenly failing due to ReferenceError: window is not defined
I've been successfully deploying a nextjs application via Dokku for past 6 months. Suddenly I'm not able to deploy anymore due to a ReferenceError: window is not defined, with minimal changes. I've reverted the changes but still receive the same error.
Since the last successful deploy a couple days ago..,

my VPS storage reached its capacity causing one of the builds to fail due to server being out of space. To fix this, I've pruned system docker images docker system prune -a
I've rebooted the VM

The application is still working by using the previous deployment, but any new deployment is failing.
       Collecting page data ...
remote: ReferenceError: window is not defined
remote:     at detect (/tmp/build/node_modules/echarts/dist/echarts.js:123:54)
remote:     at /tmp/build/node_modules/echarts/dist/echarts.js:97:9
remote:     at /tmp/build/node_modules/echarts/dist/echarts.js:22:68
remote:     at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/build/node_modules/echarts/dist/echarts.js:25:2)
remote:     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1546:14)
remote:     at Object..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1689:10)
remote:     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1318:32)
remote:     at Function._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1128:12)
remote:     at TracingChannel.traceSync (node:diagnostics_channel:315:14)
remote:     at wrapModuleLoad (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:218:24)
remote: 
remote: > Build error occurred
remote: Error: Failed to collect page data for /dashboard
remote:     at /tmp/build/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js:1171:15
remote:     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:105:5) {
remote:   type: 'Error'
remote: }
       
-----> Build failed
       
       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
       
       Some possible problems:
       
       - Node version not specified in package.json
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version
       
       Love,
       Heroku
       
remote:  !     Failure during app build

it looks like suddenly node build is failing due to a echarts window not defined error (a package I utilize) but this builds successfully locally via npm run build.
I'm trying to figure out next steps and also understand what happened and why it is suddenly failing with no changes.
Thank you

Is it possible that you had a cached version of some other dependency that didn't have this issue, but now that the cache is gone, the error appears? Try clearing out your local node_modules to see if the error appears locally.
